# EasyMock Expectation with a void method and an object array as argument?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, testng, easymock

When using EasyMock to set expectations for a void method, is it possible to specify an Object array as one of the arguments for the method?

For example, if we have something like this:

```
Errors mockErrors = createMock(Errors.class);
...
mockErrors.rejectValue(Object[]{"5", "2"});
mockErrors.replay();

classUnderTest.someMethod();
```

whereby within ClassUnderTest, someMethod calls rejectValue(Object[]{"5", "2"});

However, despite the expectation being set to exactly what is being called, easy mock complains about an unexpected method call.

```
>     Unexpected method call rejectValue(["5", "2"]):
>         rejectValue(["5", "2"]): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

I presume that it's because under the hood it's relying on equals method on an Object[] and as the two are different it returns false and does not satisfy the condition.

Is there a way around it? As I'm not setting expectation using expect() I can use any()... is there a way of doing the same on a void method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mockErrors.rejectValue(aryEq(new Object[] {"5", "2"}));
```

See [the javadoc](http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/3.1/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#aryEq%28T%5B%5D%29) for details.

Comment: The javadoc link has been moved. See all method declarations for `aryEq` at http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html